# Order Email Notification stopped working in Wordpress

Tags: plugins, wordpress, woocommerce, email

The email notification that I used to receive after every successful transaction suddenly stopped working (coincedentally) after uninstalling Smart Manager plugin. I use the WooCommerce theme (). Can anyone help me resolve this issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Woocommerce Seetings-> Notifications. Enable notification for successful checkouts there.

Comment: Thanks for your response Aryan. However, the notifications are enabled. Wondering if the problem lies elsewhere.